# Mootools: get css property

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I am new to `mootools`, how to get `css` property of an element as in `jQuery` `Element.css('background')`?

Sultan

Comment: Problem solved here is the code `$$('.element').get({'styles': 'background'})`

Comment: You could also get in this way : .getStyle('background') (http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style#Element:getStyle)

Comment: Such a power, such a flexibility!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the element has an ID, e.g. container, then use:

```
var container_style = $('container').getStyle('background');
```

`$$` is generally used for an array of elements, such as multiple elements with the same class name.